# Find the unique area from the overlapping rectangles in python

Tags: python, opencv, intersection, area

I am trying to find the unique area from multiple bounded box generated to find the screen capture by the products in python

[image]

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried IOU but the issue is there can be unknown number of combinations

Comment: what means "unique area" ? One rectangle area with all boxes ?

Comment: Unique area means a portion of rectangle which is intersected by other rectangles should be consider only once .
Consider above shape is transformed into a single n-dimension polygon and we need the find the area of that polygon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try threshold the image by colors first (using either [HSV threshold](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html), or RGB).

Then having several binary images, you can use [Contour Approximation (number 4 on the page)](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) feature, using  Douglas-Peucker algorithm. Fill the resulting bounding boxes.

Afterwards, you can subtract resulting binary images from one another to find exact areas of intersections.

Hope it helps!